# how to validate particular domain with emailID in java

Tags: java

```
public static boolean isValidEmail(String emailID) {
    String EMAIL_REGEX = "^[\\w-_\\.+]*[\\w-_\\.]\\@([\\w]+\\.)+[\\w]+[\\w]$";
    Boolean b = emailID.matches(EMAIL_REGEX);
    return b;

}
```

this is my code  using this code i am able to validate emailID but i want Unique email ID validation whose domain is @itspl.com i.e if user Enter x@gmail.com then it should display wrong Email ID if they Enter X@itspl.com then it show correct please tell me how i will do this .

Comment: Dev Try the accepted answer with DevResearch@itsplAcom

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply restrict your reg ex with the domain like below

```
 String EMAIL_REGEX = "^[\\w-_\\.+]*[\\w-_\\.]\\@itspl\\.com";
```

Answer (score 1):

Please try this

```
String emailID = "wombat@itspl.com";
String EMAIL_REGEX = "^[\\w-_\\.+]*[\\w-_\\.]\\@itspl\\.com$";
System.out.println(emailID.matches(EMAIL_REGEX));
```

prints **true**

```
String emailID = "wombat@itsplAcom";
String EMAIL_REGEX = "^[\\w-_\\.+]*[\\w-_\\.]\\@itspl\\.com$";
System.out.println(emailID.matches(EMAIL_REGEX));
```

prints **false**

Without the last `.` being escaped, the wrong results is returned

```
String emailID = "wombat@itsplAcom";
String EMAIL_REGEX = "^[\\w-_\\.+]*[\\w-_\\.]\\@itspl.com$";
System.out.println(emailID.matches(EMAIL_REGEX));
```

**Falsely** prints **true**